# How can I populate mysql databse using seeds.rb?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I have a github repo of a rails app. How can I use seeds.rb to put the details into my sql database(I am using php for development.)?

Comment: Did you read the manual? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data

Comment: You could set up the Rails app in separate directory, point it to your database and run `rake db:seed`. However depending on your environment that might be a big hassle. There's no way to just load seeds.rb to db without rails, not that I know of.